# Handling the View with doorkeeper and rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api, doorkeeper

I am making a new Rails API project( `$ rails new <project-name> --api` ) with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper).

Reading the Doorkeeper readme, I found the it is possiable to do `Doorkeeper::Application.new :name => 'test', :redirect_uri => 'http://test.com'`.

However, for the [requesting authorization page](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/authorization-flow#requesting-authorization) that `[Users] should sign in and click on Authorize`, there is no "view" in `rails-api` projects.

How can I handle this view?

Thanks!